# How to bypass the apturl and download the deb file directly?

Tags: apt, games, downloads, apturl

I want to download this game 0A.D. from http://www.playdeb.net/software/0%20A.D. .deb file.  They keep their file up to date with the source code, so they have the newest versions. I don't want apturl to handle it. I just want the deb so I can install in on a machine at home which does not have an internet connection. How can I just download the .deb file it points to.

If fact it does not matter what my reason is. I just want to be able to download a file that is manged by apturl. It is easier if all my friends don't have to download the file at the same time to play, I just share it from a shared drive on my machine.

Comment: what is the game name?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`apturl` isn't obfuscating anything here - the owners of the websites that use it are. All `apturl` does is take an `apt://<package>` link and spawn the Software Center for that package. Nothing more, nothing less. It knows nothing about the server, nothing about how to download it.

In that vein, there's nothing to be had here. To use [Get/Play]Deb you install their repo and their website just directs the package manager to the right package.

If you want to download the packages, you have to use your noggin, remember the package name (not all of it, autocomplete will help you out) and run something like this in a terminal:

```
apt-get download <package>
```

That will download the package to your current directory.

Comment: "apt-get download" thanks for the help. That is some thing I will remember.

Answer (score 2):

I emailed playdeb and this is the response they gave me

> to me, GetDeb
> Hello,
>
> you can download the packages from one of our mirrors,
> e.g.:
> http://mirror.informatik.uni-mannheim.de/pub/mirrors/getdeb/ubuntu/pool/games/
>
> Aaron Nel:
> I would like to download the .deb files. Is there away I can get around your apturl's  and just download the deb files. I want to be able to share the files with my less connected friends.

Answer (score 1):

Go to the launchpad page of 0.a.d.

For example dev-snapshots: https://launchpad.net/~wfg/+archive/0ad.dev/+packages

Click "View package details"

Select the desired package. The package details will show up. In the section "Package files" you can download the .deb.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I still want to use the other web site, which follows code releases much closer and will let me get the latest versions.

Answer (score 1):

You can download the `.deb` files from the PlayDeb apt repository. This is browsable at http://archive.getdeb.net/ubuntu/rpoo. From here you go to the "0" directory (because OAD starts with a 0).

In this case, it is highly likely that you want both the `0ad` and `0ad-data` packages. Make sure you get two with the same version number - preferably the version mentioned at the bottom of [the game's PlayDeb page](http://www.playdeb.net/software/0AD).

So in this case (assuming Ubuntu 11.04, as that's the latest version PlayDeb has the game for) you want:

- http://archive.getdeb.net/ubuntu/rpool/games/0/0ad/0ad_0.0.0+r10288~alpha-1~getdeb1_i386.deb
- http://archive.getdeb.net/ubuntu/rpool/games/0/0ad/0ad_0.0.0+r10288~alpha-1~getdeb1_amd64.deb
- http://archive.getdeb.net/ubuntu/rpool/games/0/0ad-data/0ad-data_0.0.0+r10288~alpha-1~getdeb1_all.deb

(which of the first two you want depends on whether you are running 32 bit or 64 bit Ubuntu)

Comment: How did you find the archive.getdeb.net.

Answer (score 0):

don't forget to first add the getdeb games repository

```
   deb http://archive.getdeb.net/ubuntu oneiric-getdeb games 
   wget -q -O- http://archive.getdeb.net/getdeb-archive.key | sudo apt-key add -
   sudo apt-get update
```

also note that this is a different repository then the getdeb for the nongame apps!
you can get better instructions from there site